# C++ exception being thrown deep in xmemory code

Tags: c++, exception

A C++ exception is being thrown when a vector's push_back method is called. In the debugger, it appears that the exception is being thrown deep in the xmemory file. Here is where I see the exception happen:

```
// TEMPLATE FUNCTION _Destroy
template<class _Ty> inline
void _Destroy(_Ty _FARQ *_Ptr)
{   // destroy object at _Ptr
    _DESTRUCTOR(_Ty, _Ptr);
}
```

It doesn't appear to be a bad_alloc exception because I tried wrapping the code in a try-catch with a bad_alloc catch handler. The code did that step in there. It always steps into the (...) catch handler. If it's not a bad_alloc exception, then what could be going on?

Comment: Are you following the [Rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) ?

Comment: what is the type of the object?  What is the type of the exception?  I'd guess that the function you show here is _not_ the origin of the exception, as destructors _very_ rarely throw exceptions. (Like: never)

Answer (score 0):

The `xmemory` header is an implementation detail of the Dinkumware implementation of the standard C++ library (which is shipping e.g. with MSVC++). The actual error is very unlikely to be related to this particular function. I don't know what the macro `_DESTRUCTOR` expands to (using the -E or /E compiler flag you can find out) but it will definitely call the destructor of the involved type. I would look at what exception this macro throws or check whether any of my destructors might throw an exception. Also, to get a better handle on what the exception might be, try to catch `std::exception const&` as it is recommended that every exception being thrown derives from this type. This is definitely true for all exceptions thrown by the standard C++ library. However, some systems throw exceptions as a result of undefined behavior which may not derive from `std::exception` (e.g. when your code ends up releasing memory multiple times). Not following this advice of deriving from `std::exception` makes debugging exceptions unfortunately quite a bit harder. When you caught a `std::exception const&` you can use the `what()` member of `std::exception` to find out what it is doing.