# Problems with #include <xmemory> on MacOS

Tags: c++

This might be a stupid newbie question but Im getting really frustrated. Im doing a school assignment i c++. Our teacher supplied us with a testprogram which tries to include something called xmemory.

```
#include <xmemory>
```

When I try to build it I get this error:

```
fatal error: 'xmemory' file not found
```

Im running CLion 2019.3.3 on MacOS 10.14.6. Also tried building it in XCode and I get the same error.

I have absolutely no idea where to start... I understand the file missing, but have no idea where it might be located or where to get it. Or even what it is for that matter :-))

**Update:** 
It looks like the problem is that xmemory is windows-specific. Anyone knows if there is something similar that works with MacOS that I can refer to instead?

Comment: It looks like a Windows-only header: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4e80caab-0064-4303-b819-67c3d1c0f577/avoiding-xmemory-inclusion-in-project?forum=vclanguage. The error messages in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967078/sets-and-xmemory-in-c) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/9109/) also suggest that it's some kind of internal header related to Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: It certainly does...

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9285162/4354477) says that it's "an implementation detail of the implementation of the standard C++ library which is shipping with MSVC++", and MSVC++ means MicroSoft Visual C++, so Windows again

Comment: You can get Windows 10 for free: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO, install it alongside your macOS using Bootcamp and install Visual Studio and start using Windows-specific headers and stuff